# pycparser.plyparser.ParseError on complex struct

Tags: python, c, ply, pycparser

I'm trying to use `pycparser` to parse this C code:

https://github.com/nbeaver/mx-trunk/blob/0b80678773582babcd56fe959d5cfbb776cc0004/libMx/d_adsc_two_theta.c

A repo with a minimal example and Makefile is here:

https://github.com/nbeaver/pycparser-problem

Using `pycparser` v2.14 (from pip) and gcc 4.9.2 on Debian Jessie.

Things I have tried:

- Pass the `-nostdinc` flag to `gcc` and including the `fake_libc_include` folder.
- Use `-D'__attribute__(x)='` to take out GCC extensions
- Use fake headers for e.g. `<sys/param.h>`
- Use the `-std=c99` in case the code is not C99 compatible.
- Reproduce the [redis example](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/on-parsing-c-type-declarations-and-fake-headers/) in case there is something weird with my machine.

This is what the traceback looks like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "just_parse.py", line 21, in <module>
    parse(path)
  File "just_parse.py", line 9, in parse
    ast = pycparser.parse_file(filename)
  File "/home/nathaniel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycparser/__init__.py", line 93, in parse_file
    return parser.parse(text, filename)
  File "/home/nathaniel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycparser/c_parser.py", line 146, in parse
    debug=debuglevel)
  File "/home/nathaniel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycparser/ply/yacc.py", line 265, in parse
    return self.parseopt_notrack(input,lexer,debug,tracking,tokenfunc)
  File "/home/nathaniel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycparser/ply/yacc.py", line 1047, in parseopt_notrack
    tok = self.errorfunc(errtoken)
  File "/home/nathaniel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycparser/c_parser.py", line 1680, in p_error
    column=self.clex.find_tok_column(p)))
  File "/home/nathaniel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycparser/plyparser.py", line 55, in _parse_error
    raise ParseError("%s: %s" % (coord, msg))
pycparser.plyparser.ParseError: in/d_adsc_two_theta.c:63:82: before: .
```

The traceback points to this line:

https://github.com/nbeaver/mx-trunk/blob/0b80678773582babcd56fe959d5cfbb776cc0004/libMx/d_adsc_two_theta.c#L63

Which in turn points to this `#define` macro:

https://github.com/nbeaver/mx-trunk/blob/0b80678773582babcd56fe959d5cfbb776cc0004/libMx/mx_motor.h#L484

Comment: I think you shall debug your python software in the first place. There is no gcc specific problem here. You shall add python tag and let python community help you.

Comment: Thanks, I did that just now.

Comment: does your c code compile and work without python? why are you not using cffi? did you report this issue in in ply/pycparser trackers?

https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/issues/new

https://github.com/dabeaz/ply/issues/new

Comment: @denfromufa Yes, the code compiles with GCC. I am not using `cffi` because I only want to parse the C code and do some static analysis. Yes, I just filed a bug report here: https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/issues/143

Comment: Is there something I am missing, or should we remove the tag ``python-cffi``?

Comment: I removed the `python-cffi` tag.

Comment: Also, I fixed an issue in the repo that made it harder to reproduce the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause appears to be the `offsetof()` function. The minimal working examples are fixed by recent commits, however:

https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/issues/87